# Willmore energy of an ellipsoid

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

Given an ellipsoid of equation 
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$
How can I calculate the Willmore energy of this surface knowing that its definition is:
$$W=\frac{1}{4}\int_S(k_1-k_2)^2dA$$where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are the principal curvatures of the surface?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curvature formulas for implicit surfaces $F(x,y,z)=0$ can be found in [Curvature formulas for implicit curves and surfaces](http://www.ann.jussieu.fr/~frey/papers/meshing/Goldman%20R.,%20Curvature%20formulas%20for%20implicit%20curves%20and%20surfaces.pdf) by Ron Goldman, with derivation. Let $H$ be the Hessian of $F$. Then the principal curvatures are 
$$k_{1,2}=\frac{-1}{|\nabla F|}\lambda_{1,2}\tag1$$
(the minus sign is arbitrary, of course)
where $\lambda_{1,2}$ are the roots of the equation 
$$\det\begin{pmatrix} H-\lambda I & \nabla F^T \\ \nabla F & 0 \end{pmatrix}=0 \tag2$$
(see equation (4.4) of the paper). Here $\nabla F$ is understood as a row vector.

Although the matrix in (2) is $4\times 4$, the fact that $H$ is diagonal in your example should help.